# Expected type `bool`, found type `&bool`

Tags: boolean, rust

I would like to take a `bool` from a `Vec<bool>` and compare it in an if statement. How do I solve the following error?

```
  |
7 |             if cell {
  |                ^^^^ expected bool, found &bool
  |
  = note: expected type `bool`
             found type `&bool`
```

`if cell.clone()` works for me but seems a bit hackisch.

Comment: You can dereference the value with `*` see [rust by example](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html) for the specifics.

Answer (score 7):

> take a `bool` from a `Vec<bool>`

Just do that:

```
let foo = vec![true];
if foo[0] { /* ... */ }
```

`bool` implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), so indexing the array will copy the value out.

If you had a reference to the boolean inside the vector, you will need to dereference it:

```
let foo = vec![true];
if let Some(val) = foo.last() {
    if *val { /* ... */ }
}
```

Or

```
let foo = vec![true];
if let Some(&val) = foo.last() {
    if val { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reposting [asteriskTheServers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879615/asterisktheserver) answer for visibility:

> You can dereference the value with `*` see [rust by example](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html) for the specifics.